# Запятые в предложении с деепричастием

Tags: пунктуация

Пойте слагая ему благочестивые громкие гимны

Answer (score 2):

**Пойте, слагая ему благочестивые громкие гимны.** Деепричастный оборот (*слагая ему благочестивые громкие гимны*) должен отделяться от основной части (*пойте*) запятой.